# How can i replace the all email address found in particular folder in linux

Tags: regex, linux, awk, grep

I have some scripts in some folder. like `/var/www/sites`

Now i want to replace all the email address hardcoded in the scripts in all folders and subfolders and replace with my email address

how can i do that.

I can find using

`grep -rn "abc@gmail.com" /var/www/sites/`

But i don't know how to use regex and replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find /var/www/sites -type f | xargs sed --in-place 's/abc@gmail\.com/mynewemail@elsewhere.com/g'
```

Comment: Yes, immediately after submitting the answer I found myself doubting the existence of a recursive flag on sed.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Try perl:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/abc@gmail.com/new@gmail.com/g' /var/www/sites/*
```

Or with perl/find:

```
find /var/www/sites/ -exec perl -p -i -e 's/abc@gmail.com/new@gmail.com/g' {} \;
```

Comment: This have the disadvantage to modify the files even if the file doesn't contains the searched string

Comment: See my edit… It won't edit, only search through, and it only matters if you do it on thousands of files, but basically you're right. ;-) Otherwise your solution takes 3 processes for each file, which may be more "unwanted" than searching through many files.

Comment: If you're concerned about modifying files that don't contain the string, then use a grep instead of find.

Comment: ...Or use perl or sed the proper way, see my post.

Answer (score 1):

Open a [shell](/questions/tagged/shell), then

if you have [bash4](/questions/tagged/bash4) :

```
oldmail="abc@gmail.com"
newmail="myemail@provider.tld"
shopt -s globstar
sed -i "/$oldmail/s/$oldmail/$newmail/g" /var/www/sites/**/*
```

if not :

```
oldmail="abc@gmail.com"
newmail="myemail@provider.tld"
find /var/www/sites -type f -exec sed -i "/$oldmail/s/$oldmail/$newmail/g" {} +
```

This solutions have the advantage to **not** modify the timestamps in the files even if the file doesn't contains the searched string, unlike `sed -i` & `perl -i -pe` solutions without a previous `grep` (I do this here with `/pattern/`)

Comment: Really? Launching a bash process with 2 subprocesses for every single file? That's horrible, if you ask me. The `bash4` solution is nice though!

Comment: Changed my find solution for something lighter ;)

Answer (score -2):

Try sed.

```
grep -rl "abc@gmail.com" /var/www/sites/ | xargs sed -i 's/oldemail/newemail/g'
```

Edit:

Took feedback into account. Sorry about the previously wrong solution!